# Verifying ideals are distinct.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

In the ring of $Z[\sqrt-5]$, I need to show that the ideals generated by 2, 3 , $1+\sqrt-5$ and $1-\sqrt-5$ are all distinct.

Ideal generated by 2 and ideal generated by 3 are distinct, is obvious. But how to I show that I cannot have $1+\sqrt-5$ as a multiple of 2, for example? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the  norm: $\;N(2)=4$, $N(3)=9$, whereas $\;N(1\pm\sqrt{-5})=6$. If one of $1\pm\sqrt{-5}$ were a multiple of $2$ or $3$, their norms would be multiples of $4$ or $9$.

As to $1+\sqrt{-5}$ being a multiple of $1-\sqrt{-5}$ (or vice versa), as they have the same norm, one of them would be a unit factor of the other. As the only units in this ring are $\pm1$, we see this is impossible.